# Django Test views.py function

Tags: javascript, jquery, python, django

I'm building a function in my views.py. Is there anyway of telling if the function is called upon. The function has some tricky tasks, so I want to make sure that it is called upon.

In other coding I would put a print statement, but I don't know how to test it.

The function will be activated from javascript in the code.

Comment: Why wouldn't a print statement work? That's what I do.

Comment: If you are testing in local, I would say just use pdb. In other case print statement should still work, check the logs and see if its getting called.

Comment: Use your browser's developer tools and watch the net tab to see when/if the view's url is called by javascript.